# In this question, what does μ stand for?

Tags: noise, gaussian

> Let $X_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,N$) be random variables describing an unknown constant signal $S$ and a noise $n_i$.
> $$X_i = \mu_i S + n_i$$

In this question what does "$\mu$" stand for? Also, can I say that $X$'s distribution is Normal with expectation of "$\mu S$" and SD of "$\sigma$"?

Full page below:

[image: Page from text]

Comment: since the text doesn't define that, give any more information about the properties of $X_i$  or use $\mu_i$ in any of the text you show, I'm afraid all we can say is that these are "probably some numbers".

Comment: (you say "in this question…", but there's not a question where the $\mu$ appear)

Comment: plus, please be more exact in your notation; your text has no variable $X$, only $X_i$; the random vector s called $\vec X$.

Comment: Well I do need to know the distribution of $/mu$ if I want to solve 3.3.1 for example, that's why I said "in this question".

Comment: yeah, but you can see just as much as we do, if not more (as we have none of the definitions leading up to this page): whether $\mu_i$ are random (there's no single $\mu$ without an index!), and if so, how they are distributed is simply not defined in your text. We can't tell you something that's simply not given.

Comment: However, the fact that the $\mu_i$ have an index strongly suggest that they are all different realizations of a random variable, indeed. Whether they are identically distributed: not defined. Whether they are independent, or independent from the noise: not defined.

Comment: Here is the first time the prof used it in the lecture notes:
https://imgur.com/a/6xinncb

Comment: And another:
https://imgur.com/a/ctZy5HL

Comment: if  you translate that equation to what you show here, then $S$ needs to be either 0 or 1  – something also not defined in the text you shared. I don't know how this relates to your lecture, but as it's given here, the text you share in your question doesn't even make all definitions necessary to understand what is asked of you here. Maybe stick to the lecture notes?

Comment: What do you mean by "stick to the lecture notes"?

Comment: there's no information we can give you about the variables used in the excerpt of the lecture notes you show, because unlike you, we don't have the rest lecture notes.

Comment: but if it is as in your 1.5.5, then no, you don't need to know the distribution of the $\mu_i$ to answer 3.3.1.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Under hypothesis $\mathcal H_1$ when $S = 1$, $\mathbf X = [\mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots, \mu_N] + [n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_N]$ while under hypothesis $\mathcal H_0$ when $S = 0$, $\mathbf X = [0, 0, \cdots, 0] + [n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_N] = [n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_N]$. Can you set up the Neyman-Pearson test now, or do you still need help?

With regard to Q. 3.3, do you know the concept of a matched filter or correlator in white Gaussian noise, or maybe just for the case when the transmitted signal is $[1,1,\cdots, 1]$? The statistic $Y$ that you need is exactly the output (at the optimum sampling instant) of a discrete-time filter *matched* to $[1,1,\cdots, 1]$, possibly "normalized" to have value $1$ by *scaling* the signal output appropriately. Remember that the  noise variances also get scaled.

What a poorly-thought-through question your professor has come up with..... Sheesh!

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I didn't have a problem with setting up the NP test, I was struggling with 3.3 since I don't know the distribution of $\mu$